# Why is my ST_Union output disproportionately large?

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, union

I have two multi-polygon geometry tables (see the figures below) in my PostGIS database and I would like to create a union of these two tables. They are ~12mb and ~1mb in size. However, the union of these two tables which I created using `ST_Union` is ~1.1gb.

The code I used

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.myunion AS 
SELECT
        ST_Union(mymultipoly1.geom ,
        mymultipoly2.geom)
FROM
        mymultipoly1,
        mymultipoly2
```

It runs fast. My only problem is the size of the output. I don't have to keep the attributes of either of the input tables. But I don't want to meddle with the geometry too much as I need to calculate the area of the output reasonably accurately. My attempts so far

1. I used `ST_Simplify(ST_Union...` (with a tolerance value of 10m) and reduced the output table by half the size.
2. I tried to use `ST_Collect(ST_Union...` which gives me the following error  `ERROR:  array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)`. I think this is because ST_Collect attempts to combine all rows of the multi polygon into one row.

I would like to know why the resulting table is huge and is there a more size-efficient way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Research "Cartesian product SQL" to better understand what your column list does in the `FROM` -- This will **not** preverve cumulative area. If  you want what ArcGIS calls a "Union", you actually need to use a `JOIN` using  ST_Intersects with ST_Intersection *and* other queries to get the parts of the  mp1 that don't overlap with any mp2, and the parts of mp2 that don't overlap with mp1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a ***geometric* union of both sets of geometries** is what you are after, this *should* be the most convenient, and conveniently also the most performant way, to do so:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.myunion AS (
  SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT geom,
           ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 0, 1) OVER () AS _clst
    FROM   (
      SELECT geom
      FROM   mymultipoly1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT geom
      FROM   mymultipoly2
    ) AS table_union
  ) AS geometric_clustering
  GROUP BY
         _clst
);
```

Here

- we first create a `UNION ALL` of both tables into `table_union`
- we then cluster that virtual table *by spatial intersection* into `geometric_clustering` - passing `eps => 0` to `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` has just his handy effect, and as an in-memory operation it is *fast* - and since we also want *isolated* geometries having a separate cluster id (`_clst`), we pass in `minpoints => 1`
- we then `ST_Union` based on `_clst`

---

**Addendum:**

Given that we are looking to minimize the operational cost of `ST_Union` to a minimum, and for a geometric union operation on multiple sets of geometries to also make sense, we need to collect

- geometries in `a` that do *not* overlap with geometries in `b`
- geometries in `b` that do *not* overlap with geometries in `a`

to simply add them into the result, and determine

- geometries in `a` that do overlap with geometries in `a`, identified by group
- geometries in `b` that do overlap with geometries in `b`, identified by group
- (groups of) geometries from above that overlap between `a` and `b`, identified by group

to then being able to create unions over the identified groups.

In row set theory we'd require multiple `JOIN` operations in sequence, spread across multiple SQL statements (and eventually *set*-`UNION`ed into a single source set), to find those candidates for the *geometric* union operation.

Using `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` here primarily serves convenience, and secondarily may boost performance.
As an in-memory operation over a simple input set-`UNION` of both tables and by setting the maximum candidate distance to `0` (read: geometries have to be within `0` distance of each other to get considered the same cluster), it is fast to identify groups of overlapping geometries, as well as adding those that are isolated (by specifying that clusters can be of size 1). As a *Window function*, it is able to assign ids (here: `_clst`) to *rows* belonging to the same cluster, and that we can later use to `GROUP BY` and `ST_Union` over.

---

**Bonus:**

Since isolated geometries will get an own `_clst` assignment each, and subsequently get passed to (and *potentially* unnecessarily processed by) `ST_Union`, we can conditionally add geometries to the result set in cases where we expect *a large amount of input geometries* to be isolated:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.myunion AS (
  WITH
    cluster AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   (
        SELECT geom,
               ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 0, 2) OVER () AS _clst
        FROM   (
          SELECT geom
          FROM   mymultipoly1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT geom
          FROM   mymultipoly2
        ) AS table_union
      ) AS geometric_clustering
      ORDER BY
             _clst NULLS FIRST
    )
  SELECT geom
  FROM   cluster
  WHERE  _clst IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM   cluster
  WHERE  _clst IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
         _clst
);
```

We set `minpoints => 2` to make the function assign `NULL`s to isolated geometries.

Comment: This does exactly what I want and also the total area looks correct. I am still trying to understand why clustering is important here though - is it only to make the code run faster?

Comment: Yes, using clustering is a way to optimize the geometries processed by ST_Union.   An alternative would be to union all the geometries of each table and then union those two results, but that is likely to be less performant (depending on data).

Answer (score 5):

The query you have uses makes a cross-join between the two layers and, for each pair of records, computes the union between the two geometries.

The total number of rows in the output will be `number of rows from layer1` * `number of rows from layer2`.

If you want to create a new table with the geometries from both layers, you don't need the spatial`st_union` operator but rather the SQL `UNION ALL` command

```sql
CREATE TABLE myschema.myunion AS 
SELECT
        mymultipoly1.geom
FROM
        mymultipoly1
UNION ALL
SELECT
        mymultipoly2.geom
FROM
        mymultipoly2
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand the difference between the outputs conceptually. If I plot the outputs from the two methods will they be the same? And will the geometric characteristics such as total area ( for ex. calculated using `ST_Area`) be the same?

Comment: Your query will have N*M geometries in it (and most of them will be the same)

Comment: It looks like `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicate rows between the various SELECT statements. I am worried if I used this method and calculate the area of the resulting geometry table, the total area will be overestimated. Is that right? How to avoid this?